# In token authentication , should data be sent along with the token?

Tags: node.js, token

(beginner here)
i have the back-end sending a token upon successful registration or login from a user ,i want to make a route to access the user details.

i could create a route like (user/) which would need the token in the header , verify that and return the user data.

or create a route like (/users/:id) and pass the id as prams from the front-end , but i would need that id sent with the token upon login/registration.

i don`t know what is the right way to do such thing ?

Answer (score 0):

I use keycloak in the frontend and backend. When the user do the login, it generate a token and you pass this token in the header to the backend. The backend will receive this token and see that user has the rule to access this endpoint and backend can access the user informations in keycloak, soo you don't need to pass some user id, just the token in this case.